# Linear independence of linear combinations confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking at page 43 of "Mathematics for Machine Learning" (made free by the publishers here: https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf), and I am confused by something:

[image]

I am not sure why {λ1 , . . . , λm} being linearly independent means that multiplying them by B so that {Bλ1 , . . . , Bλm} is also linearly independent. Basically I would like there to be one more sentence at that last paragraph that says "We can factor out B because ...". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's missing here is the fact that, because $B$ has linearly independent columns, the vector equation $Bv = 0$ has only the solution $v = 0$. Taking this for granted for the moment, we know from $(2.72)$ that
$$\sum_{j=1}^m \psi_j x_j = 0 \implies B \sum_{j=1}^m \psi_j \lambda_j = 0,$$
which is just $Bv = 0$ where $v = \sum_{j=1}^m \psi_j \lambda_j$. This must mean that
$$\sum_{j=1}^m \psi_j \lambda_j = 0,$$
which implies $\psi_j = 0$ for all $j$, since the $\lambda_j$s are linearly independent. That completes the proof of the $x_j$s being linearly independent.

The missing ingredient, $Bv = 0 \implies v = 0$, follows fairly immediately from the linear independence of the columns of $B$. If $v = [v_1, \ldots, v_k]^\top$ is a column vector of appropriate size, then, by the definition of matrix multiplication,
$$Bv = \sum_{i=1}^k v_i b_i.$$
So $Bv = 0$ only has the solution $v_i = 0$ for all $i$, i.e. $v = 0$.

Comment: thanks for the help. After some more time of understanding exactly what a basis is, I am able to visualise where I was getting confused before. The way I see it now is by taking B out like that we're kind of "straightening" the axis like how we normally have them in a graph, for simplicity, then after we've summed them up, we skew the axis back to how they were before. if it's linearly independent on the normal straight axis, then it carries over naturally to the skewed axis since everything is scaled the same

Answer (score 0):

I think the author argues about when the condition $\sum \psi_j x_j = 0$ is fulfilled. The argument is that this will be the case when $\mathbf{B} \mathbf{\lambda_j}$ is linearly independent, which is the case when ${\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m}$ are linearly independent, given the independence of $\mathbf{B}$.